# async/await unit test code coverage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, visual-studio-2013, async-await

How to write unit test for async/await method, I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Suppose we have a async method:

```
public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    ...
    await _service.DoInternalAsync();
    ...
}
```

Since I am using the latest version of Visual Studio, it has good support to the async method unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task DoSomthingAsyncTest()
{
    ...
    await _objectUnderTest.DoSomethingAsync();
    // how to verify the result??? here is what I did
    _service.Verify(_ => _.DoInternalAsync());
}
```

Basically, I have two questions:

1. As commented in the code, how to verify the `Task` result? Did I do that right way?
2. If I run that test, the VS would say test passed. But when I check the code coverage, the `await _service.DoInternalAsync()` sentence seems not be covered, from the view of *Code Coverage Results*, it prompt the `MoveNext()` sentence has 6 not covered blocks. What's wrong within it?

Comment: Since your `async` method does not return anything else than a task, simply assert that your mock of `Service` was called. No need to test anything else, the unit tests inside your `service` class already covers its behavior. If you had a return value, there's a way to mock classes with async methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, from my research, the code coverage issue is a Visual Studio bug in latest version Visual Studio 2013, they would fix/enhance it in next major version.

Quote from the [feedback](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/816884/microsoft-unit-test-coverage-shows-partial-covered-code-for-async-method-call-in-unit-test-having-microsoft-unit-test-framework-using-moq):

> The issue that you are seeing is due to a bug from our end due to which we do not have complete support for the async/await pattern in code coverage as yet. The work is pending and should be something we deliver in the next major update/release. There are no clean workarounds for this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The reason the code is not shown as being covered has to do with how async methods are implemented.  The C# compiler actually translates the code in async methods into a class that implements a state machine, and transforms the original method into a stub that initialized and invokes that state machine.  Since this code is generated in your assembly, it is included in the code coverage analysis.

If you use a task that is not complete at the time the code being covered is executing, the compiler-generated state machine hooks up a completion callback to resume when the task completes.  This more completely exercises the state machine code, and results in complete code coverage (at least for statement-level code coverage tools).

A common way to get a task that is not complete at the moment, but will complete at some point is to use Task.Delay in your unit test.  However, that is generally a poor option because the time delay is either too small (and results in unpredictable code coverage because sometimes the task is complete before the code being tests runs) or too large (unnecessarily slowing the tests down).

A better option is to use "await Task.Yield()".  This will return immediately but invoke the continuation as soon as it is set.

Another option - though somewhat absurd - is to implement your own awaitable pattern that has the semantics of reporting incomplete until a continuation callback is hooked up, and then to immediately complete.  This basically forces the state machine into the async path, providing the complete coverage.

To be sure, this is not a perfect solution.  The most unfortunate aspect is that it requires modification to production code to address a limitation of a tool.  I would much prefer that the code coverage tool ignore the portions of the async state machine that are generated by the compiler.  But until that happens, there aren’t many options if you really want to try to get complete code coverage.

A more complete explanation of this hack can be found here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2014/11/17/code-coverage-with-async-await.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: OK, I added a summary of the option as well as the link to the more in depth article.